# Casting CWnd pointer to CEdit pointer in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Found some strange issue. In my MFC application I am trying to cast CWnd pointer to CEdit one. I retrieve CWnd pointer through the GetFocus function. When I am doing `dynamic_cast<CEdit*>(pWnd)`, it returns 0. What can it be?

Comment: Are you sure that your `CWnd` pointer is actually a pointer to a `CEdit` control?

Comment: Yeap. I've checked that it points to CEdit control. When I call GetDlgCtrlID, it returns ID of the control.

Comment: Are you sure that RTTI is enabled? You can check this in your C++ compiler settings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, the MFC libraries are not compiled with RTTI enabled, so `dynamic_cast` isn't going to work anyway.

Secondly, the `CWnd*` returned by `CWnd::FromHandle` is either the extant `CWnd`, or if there is none, a flyweight wrapper around an `HWND`. If the flyweight wrapper is returned, it will not be a `CEdit`, even if the underlying `HWND` refers to an edit control.

You will only get a `CEdit` if you have already created a `CEdit` to hold the `HWND`.

If you want to know that the `CWnd*` you get is for an already-existing object, use `CWnd::FromHandlePermanent`

To get a `CEdit*` you need to create one explicitly, then call `Attach` to attach it to the `HWND`.

Alternatively if you want to cheat, `CEdit` has no data members or virtual functions and inherits directly from `CWnd` so you could use a (theoretically unsafe) `static_cast`, since it has the exact same in-memory layout.

Comment: Well actually static_cast works fine. The only point is that i need to check what kind of element has a focus. Therefore I thought that I can you dynamic_cast.

Comment: No, you need to do `GetClassName(HWND)`.